# Fullscreen not working with keyboard input on Safari/iOS with iPAD

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, fullscreen

I'm working on a web page that needs to go full screen and receive keyboard input when it is full screen (it is an interactive keyboard driven game).

I'm able to call document.body.requestFullScreen or document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen to make this work correctly on desktop browsers, but when I try it on Safari/iOS for iPad, the page enters full screen mode, but exits full screen at the first interaction on the page such as any click or typed key.

How do I get iPad/Safari to stay in full screen mode until the escape key is typed to exit full screen?

Update: if I query [document.webkitFullScreenKeyboardInputAllowed](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/document/1629394-webkitfullscreenkeyboardinputall/) on the console, it is false for both Safari desktop and Safari iPad. But keyboard input works fine on Safari desktop but not on Safari iPad.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to that problem? Having the exact same problem as you...

Comment: Unfortunately not!

Comment: Yeah I eventually found out that this is indeed not possible, but still thanks for the reply :)